# Cache expired time for all pages in liferay

Tags: caching, liferay

Is it possible to set cache expired time for whole pages in liferay?
I found next solution but it's disabling caching in browser at all. Is it possible to set expiring time for whole pages?

```
#
# Set this to true if you want the portal to force the browser cache to be
# disabled. It will only disable the cache for the rendered HTML response.
# It will not have an impact on static content or other resources.
#
browser.cache.disabled=true

#
# Set this true if you want to disable the cache for authenticated users.
# This property is not read when the property
# "browser.cache.signed.in.disabled" is true. This is useful to ensure that
# authenticated users cannot go to the sign in page by clicking on the back
# button in their browsers.
#
browser.cache.signed.in.disabled=true
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set 'Expires' header configuring liferay **HeaderFilter** filter:

- [com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.header.HeaderFilter](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/servlet/filters/header/HeaderFilter.java)

Liferay filters are configured in **WEB-INF/liferay-web.xml**, default configuration is:

- https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/docroot/WEB-INF/liferay-web.xml

Out of the box, Liferay only adds "Expires" and "Cache-control" headers to some URL patterns, see:

- [filter definitions: WEB-INF/liferay-web.xml lines 144-207](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/f75ebcea0ea819d67057eb39e8b4c42964e90d08/portal-web/docroot/WEB-INF/liferay-web.xml#L144-L207)
- [filter-mapping definitions: WEB-INF/liferay-web.xml lines 570-617](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/f75ebcea0ea819d67057eb39e8b4c42964e90d08/portal-web/docroot/WEB-INF/liferay-web.xml#L570-L617)

So you have to create:

1. new filter entry with the headers you want to add
2. new filter-mapping with the urls you want to modify